# Spring boot Unit tests by mocking all Data Base compenents

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I want to Unit test a **Service A** which uses several **JpaRepositories**. I know that I can use `@MockBean` annotation to mock my repositories, however, **all unit tests fails** because Spring requires to have data base connection to start.

I have first try to mock `DataSource` and `EntityManagerFactory` beans but it does not work because there is another bean which calls the DataSource bean to connect to the data base and the **mocked DataSource returns null**.

My alternative is to use a **H2 database** only to fool Spring start but the H2 database is never really used because I mock all repositories that I need (and I don't want to test my Jpa Repositories). I **don't like this solution** because I consider it heavy (because of the initialisation of the H2 DB at each `@SpringBootTest`) and in addition to this, the H2 DB is not really used for what it is made for.

Someone have a correct solution to unit test services which depend on JpaRepositories which
themselves depends on SQL DB connection?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my solution. I need to use the annotation `SpringBootTest` by specifying the service class that I want test.

Example: `@SpringBootTest(ServiceA.class)`. In that way, Spring will only create necessary context for the `ServiceA` without trying to create datasource connection, etc.

In addition to this, I can use the annotation `@ContextConfiguration` to specify all test configuration classes I need.

Here a link which also helped me to create UTs for my different services. It does not use my solution but it can help:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/unit-testing-services-endpoints-and-repositories-in-spring-boot-4b7d9dc2b772/